# What's the most efficient way to store time zone info in Realm?

Tags: ios, macos, nsdate, realm, foundation

I have a Realm object that contains an `NSDate` timestamp, representing the time at which a user recorded something. I need to add time zone info to this, so that I know what the local time zone was when the user created the object (in order to do accurate date formatting and comparisons).

There will be many of these objects in the Realm db (possibly several of these created each day the app is used), but overall I don't think you can say it will be an excessively large number (a busy user might create a few thousand of these objects per year of app usage).

It seems the simplest design is to store the `timeZoneName` as a string (`NSTimeZone` is identified by a `name` such as "America/New_York"). That would result in a string of roughly 10-20 characters repeated with every realm object.

That's a lot of duplication of only a few possible string values. Should I bother trying to optimize this? For example, have a separate TimeZoneInfo realm entity that would have a single property for the time zone name, and ensure that there's only one such entity per time zone.

#### Clarification

Let me make this a more objective question. What would consume the least amount of space in a Realm database?

Option 1:

Entity with a String property storing the `name` of an NSTimeZone. This name value has an average length of 15 characters. There can be thousands of instances of this Entity.

Option 2:

EntityA with a String property storing the `name` of an NSTimeZone. There will only be a few instances of this (name is a unique value).
EntityB references EntityA (it has a property of type EntityA). There can be thousands of instances of EntityB.

Basically, is it more efficient to store thousands of strings or thousands of entity references?

Comment: Minutes offset from GMT, I would imagine.  If you just want the right time then it's not important to know what country the time was recorded in.  Alternatively record all times in GMT.

Comment: Good idea, but I do want to be able to recreate a "full" `NSTimeZone` object, with a proper `abbreviation` value, for display on screen. I can't get all of this info when recreating an NSTimeZone using `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT`.

Comment: OK, saving the abbreviation is the way then.  However as you say each `NSTimeZone` object has 1+ abbreviations, so it should be taken from the device recording the time, not from the `NSTimeZone` object.

Comment: I read the first paragraph several times but I still don't see why you would need to store the time zone. You don't need to know the time zone in order to do accurate date formatting and comparisons between dates. The way NSDate works is save the number of seconds from a reference date and time. So it doesn't matter if the one user time was 1:00pm, and then 5 minutes later another user save a date and his local time is 8:05am. The system saves the date in a way that it knows that there's only 5 minuted difference between them. And if you do comparisons between them it would work.

Comment: @pteofil I need to format dates, and group by calendar date, based on the time zone that was used when the object was created. For example, a user may record an event at 2015-05-19 23:30 local time. Then a week later the user flies three time zones east and looks at that data. It should still display "2015-05-19 23:30", even though that absolute NSDate value would be formatted as "2015-05-20 02:30" using the current device time zone. Thus I need to know something about the original time zone for each object.

Comment: I see. You could simply store a String with the date already formated you got it from user, beside the NSDate then. I don't know if you would still need it, but from the 2 you could deduct the timezone if you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 will use less space, but the difference may not be worth caring about in your case.

With 5000 entries and Option 1 you'd be looking at 160KB of string data (for short strings, the storage size is rounded up to a power of two for O(1) indexing within each slab of data), plus a few hundred bytes of data structure overhead. If storing the abbreviation is sufficient, then you'd be at more like 20KB of string data and a similar amount of overhead. With Option 2 you'd just have the unique string data plus 1 byte per entry (assuming that the user doesn't visit a very large number of time zones).

Comment: I concur it's not worth the effort to optimize in this case. Are you saying the to-one reference between the entities only requires one byte per entry?

Comment: The reference is just the row index of the target, and ints are stored using the minimum width needed to store the maximum value of any entry. As a result, if there's no more than 256 target objects (or only the first 256 are linked to), each link only uses a single byte to store what row it links to.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the detailed info.

Comment: Well, the rule for optimizations, it's always to measure to see if you really need it. I would go for option 2, not because it should use less space (which may be insignificant anyway), but because it follows the same pattern that we use when storing objects in the databases. You have one object and many references to it, instead of countless copies of the same object.